# Delphi: Generic function for loading a function from a DLL library

Tags: function, delphi, dll

IDE: Delphi XE6

I am trying to write a generic function for loading a function from a DLL library. I am unsure whether this seemingly working code (tested on `User32.dll` and `BlockInput` function) is well-written or needs major / minor adjustments. As I am in no way an expert on DLLs, that is why I ask.

---

```
function LoadFunctionFromLibrary(const LibraryName, FunctionName: string; out FunctionPointer: Pointer): Boolean;

var
  LibraryHandle, ModuleHandle: THandle;

begin
  Result := False;
  FunctionPointer := nil;

  LibraryHandle := Winapi.Windows.LoadLibrary(PChar(LibraryName));
  if LibraryHandle = 0 then Exit;

  try

    ModuleHandle := Winapi.Windows.GetModuleHandle(PChar(LibraryName));

    if ModuleHandle <> 0 then begin
      FunctionPointer := Winapi.Windows.GetProcAddress(ModuleHandle, PChar(FunctionName));
      if FunctionPointer <> nil then Result := True;
    end;

  finally
    Winapi.Windows.FreeLibrary(LibraryHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: After FreeLibrary() FunctionPointer is no longer valid.

Comment: After you have called `LoadLibrary()`, there's no need to call `GetModuleHandle()`. Pass `LibraryHandle` to `GetProcAddress()`. Refer to MSDN docs [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx). Repeatedly loading and freeing a library is a waste. Instead just check if already loaded before you need it and load if not loaded, otherwise just use it.

Comment: You can't do it like this because you need the library to remain alive so long as you hold a reference to the function. Why not use implicit linking anyway? It's so much simpler.

Comment: If you do not have a mandatory task of unloading libraries, do not call FreeLibrary. After procces terminated system clear all handles.

Comment: This question seems more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for my ignorance, but what does it mean *implicit linking way*?

Comment: @JerryDodge That may be from your point of view, but as David pointed out and Branko too, I do it wrong all along. That is why I asked here first. Then I might go to CodeReview. Thank you.

Comment: @Vasek So, there is some *garbage collection* in place, thank you for the information.

Comment: @Branko Excellent point, thank you for the information.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I completely missed that, many thanks.

Comment: Implicit linking is when the linking is done automatically by the loader when the dll loads. Achieved using the external keyword in Delphi.